# Optimizing a four-year-old MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I developed an application with MySQL 5.1 back-end four years ago. After that, I only gave remote support a couple of times, but that too for application crashes, and not for database. The database is still running well. The customer takes the backup on decided schedules. I want to optimize the database as I think in these years many records have been deleted and many added.

How do I tune up the database and bring it into proper shape? What things need attention?

Comment: I am sure there are other people with old databases that have wondered about an issue like this. A +1 for bringing this question out into the open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you could so to eliminate table fragmentation and allocate proper caching resources:

Option 1 : Run [**OPTIMIZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) on every table. This will shrink each table individually and compute index statistics for all tables.

Option 2 : mysqldump everything and reload backup. Naturally, each table gets dropped and recreated without table fragmentation. Indexes are also rebuilt.

You may also want to [**compute the proper size for InnoDB Buffer Pool and MyISAM Key Cache**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194). Whatever number comes out as the recommended sizes, make sure the combined size of [**innodb_buffer_pool_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) and [**key_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) does not exceed 75% of the RAM installed on the machine.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to optimize the database as I think in these years many records
>   have been deleted and many added.

You have some other reason for wanting to fiddle with a database that is "running well"?

Good reasons might include:

- The backups are getting unmanageably large
- The customer has mentioned a specific area of performance they want improved

If you don't have a good reason, then my advice would be to do nothing

Comment: I voted you up, because you have a valid point. But I don't agree with you on that: rebuilding indexes, statistics, revising backup plans, verifying backups, verifying permissions for old users...there's so much to check on a server that's not been touched for a few years.

Comment: I'll upvote this one because your point is valid for low-trafficked sites, that do not log visits, and have a fair amount of the working set data cached all the time. In that instance, doing nothing is the thing to do. But a little routine maintenance never hurts.