# I have lots of free memory.  How do I use it to increase performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, memory, linux

I am running Litespeed (with suExec, PHP SAPI), MySQL, DirectAdmin, named on a VPS with a 16-core Xeon CPU and 2GB RAM.

Currently, only 300 MB out of 2048 are used. It might sound a stupid, but **how do i make the vps use more RAM?**

my.cnf:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock


[mysqld]
port                                            = 3306
socket                                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-locking
key_buffer                                      = 512M
max_allowed_packet                              = 8M
table_cache                                     = 4096
sort_buffer_size                                = 16M
read_buffer_size                                = 8M
join_buffer_size                                = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size                    = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size                 = 128M
myisam_repair_threads                   = 1
myisam_recover
max_heap_table_size                             = 8M
tmp_table_size                                  = 8M
thread_cache_size                               = 8
thread_concurrency                              = 8
query-cache-type                                = 1
query_cache_limit                               = 4M
query-cache-size                                = 16M

log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysqlslowqueries.log
local-infile = 0
wait_timeout = 10
interactive_timeout = 15
max_connections = 35

character-set-server            = utf8
default-character-set           = utf8

skip-networking
skip-federated
skip-symbolic-links

skip-innodb
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 4M
write_buffer = 4M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
read_buffer = 8M
write_buffer = 8M

[mysqld_safe]
open-files-limit = 8192
```

I actually **do** need to increase MySQL performance because it's the most cpu-consumming process and there are queries that can't be optimized but take some time to execute.

Any suggestions on how to efficiently use memory to increase performance would be appreciated.

Comment: Memory usage is not necessarily directly tied to CPU load.

Comment: i know that but think about mysql query caching...it's exactly related to memory and cpu load.

Comment: RAM disk your SQL data folder ;)

Comment: @Tim nice I almost tried that once )))

Comment: Will it help? If it is CPU loaded then IO is not the problem - only more efficient programming or more cpu cores will help. Normalyl ram helps, but normally databases are not io and not cpu limited.

Comment: Can you update your question with some additional details? What's size of database on disk? What's the [index usage](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5799/180)? Are you only using MyISAM (or also InnoDB)?

Comment: Related sorta: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8193/how-can-i-make-my-ssis-process-consume-more-resources-and-run-faster

Answer (score 5):

Memory can help you by caching and thus reducing I/O.

However, that won't reduce CPU usage which is your problem. This is an unusual bottleneck, as CPUs are insanely fast for most database work and I/O tends to be the bottleneck.

In your case, it is even more inusual, because you have 16-cores and VPSs tend not to have great I/O performance. First of all, make sure that you are CPU bound. `vmstat` should help here.If you have high numbers on the `wa` column, you are probably I/O bound; high numbers on the `us` column could indicate that you are really CPU bound.

If you are CPU bound, analyze what queries are you executing and why they take long to complete. You are either executing a lot of queries/s or they include complex calculations (i.e. aggregates, functions, etc.). The solution for the former is usually caching on the frontend, which means executing less queries. The latter is solved by simplifying your queries (if possible- you might have queries which are needlessly complex) and calculating stuff once and reusing it (say you have lots of aggregate queries; create a table with the aggregation results and query that instead of running aggregates continuously). The most efficient way to research about this is by logging which queries you are running and analyzing the log- tools exist which do this neatly.

If you are I/O bound, then you can tune memory usage, although the OS cache is often working correctly. Take a look at `free`:

```
$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       6122892    5903564     219328          0     257020    3119240
-/+ buffers/cache:    2527304    3595588
Swap:     11956220      65980   11890240
```

The first line of numbers accounts for memory usage *including* OS caches, the second doesn't; by comparing both you can see how OS caching is working. Also, `vmstat` will already tell you how much I/O you are performing (`bi`, `bo` columns). Often, the key to solving I/O problems is query tuning and indexing; indexing prevents full table scans (i.e. reading the entire table to get a limited set of data, which causes excessive and unnecessary I/O). Again, logging queries is most effective here- running `EXPLAIN` on the queries will tell you which operations the database is performing to execute the query, which often leads you to understanding inefficiencies in the query (and altering the query to solve them) or finding out about needed indexes.