# Drupal 7 Uses InnoDB, so do I need other configs?

Tags: mysql, innodb, my.cnf

If I'm optimizing a database that will be delivering multiple Drupal 7 websites, all using InnoDB, do I need to worry about `[myisamchk`] & `[isamchk]` sections, or can I just worry about the stuff within `[mysqld]`?

I'm assuming if I delete these sections, that the defaults will just kick in if they are needed.

I'm trying to document, outline my.conf best practices here http://groups.drupal.org/node/289613

Answer (score 1):

The other group headers have no bearing on InnoDB whatsoever. `[mysqld]` is all you really need.

With regard to InnoDB itself, you will need to tune InnoDB in many aspects

## System Tablespace / Individual Tablespaces

- `Sep 26, 2012` : [How do I shrink the innodb file ibdata1 without dumping all databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24942/how-do-i-shrink-the-innodb-file-ibdata1-without-dumping-all-databases/24963#24963)
- `Jul 05, 2012` : [Move ibdata1, set innodb_data_file_path](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20448/move-ibdata1-set-innodb-data-file-path/20451#20451)
- `Apr 19, 2012` : [MySql - Clean ibdata1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16747/mysql-clean-ibdata1/16759#16759)
- `Apr 01, 2012` : [Is innodb_file_per_table advisable?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15906/is-innodb-file-per-table-advisable/15907#15907)

## Buffer Pool

- `Oct 22, 2012` : [How much memory do I need for innodb buffer pool?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27471/how-much-memory-do-i-need-for-innodb-buffer-pool/27472#27472)
- `Jun 13, 2012` : [What to set innodb_buffer_pool and why..?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/what-to-set-innodb-buffer-pool-and-why/19181#19181)

## Transaction Logs

- `Jan 17, 2013` : [MySQL 5.5 - Innodb - innodb_log_file_size higher than 4GB combined?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33061/mysql-5-5-innodb-innodb-log-file-size-higher-than-4gb-combined/33064#33064)
- `Feb 16, 2011` : [How to safely change MySQL innodb variable 'innodb_log_file_size'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/how-to-safely-change-mysql-innodb-variable-innodb-log-file-size/1265#1265)

## Multiple CPU / Multiple Core Engagament

- `May 21, 2012` : [MySQL - Installing InnoDB Plugin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18203/mysql-installing-innodb-plugin/18240#18240)
- `Mar 16, 2012` : [Using multiple cores for single MySQL queries on Debian](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15146/using-multiple-cores-for-single-mysql-queries-on-debian/15185#15185)
- `Nov 24, 2011` : [Why mysql 5.5 slower than 5.1 (linux,using mysqlslap)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8384/why-mysql-5-5-slower-than-5-1-linux-using-mysqlslap/8385#8385)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5926/multi-cores-and-mysql-performance/5968#5968)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more than one core?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5666/possible-to-make-mysql-use-more-then-one-core/5670#5670)

## Epilogue

There are so many other aspects I have no time to write about because I probably have written it already. [Please see all my posts on InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:877%20%5Binnodb%5D).

What is also worth noting is that you should be using the latest version of MySQL

- [MySQL 5.6.10 now supports FULLTEXT indexing. You need to test this fully](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/full-text-search-with-innodb/231902587#).
- [InnoDB in MySQL 5.6 is faster than InnoDB in MySQL 5.5](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/database/)

On a side note, did you know [the StackExchange has a Drupal Q&A site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) ? I have [posted answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:989%20%5Bmysql%5D) there as well.

Comment: Thanks RolandoMySQLDBA - this is a useful list.  I wanted to post to the DBA list as I figured it would be a better place to get feedback like this. It's useful to get this direction.

Comment: I'm not clear from the issue on [innodb_file_per_table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24942/how-do-i-shrink-the-innodb-file-ibdata1-without-dumping-all-databases/24963#24963) if it is needed as it seems to be defined that way by default.  Also, it's unclear if  `innodb_file_per_table` or `innodb_file_per_table=1` are the same.

Comment: Don't worry. Setting `innodb_file_per_table` or `innodb_file_per_table=1` is synonymous. The default for `innodb_file_per_table` is 1 for MySQL 5.6 GA (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table) and 0 for MySQL 5.5 GA (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_file_per_table)