# Remove InnoDB files (ibdata1 and iblog files) after migration to MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I changed the only two `InnoDB` tables on a replication slave to `MyISAM`, so the slave now only has `MyISAM` tables.

**Can I now remove the `ibdata1` file completely?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you do not have a single InnoDB table, then yes, you can remove the `ibdata` file and the `ib_logfile[01]` files.

However, note:

- With MySQL 5.6 there are system InnoDB tables, which means you don't want to remove the InnoDB files ever.
- It is best done when the server is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

The file ibdata1 is tablespace for the InnoDB Engine.If you remove it you will not be able to Start MySQL Server.

If you don't have `InnoDB` tables still you should not remove `ibdata1` file.When you install MySQL `ibdata1` is created by default with initial size of 10MB and has four types of information

1. Table Data
2. Table Indexes
3. MVCC (Multiversioning Concurrency Control) Data
4. Table Metadata
5. Double Write Buffer
6. Insert Buffer

Some times ibdata1 grows endlessly,In Case you need help on how to shrink ibdata1 size you can follow steps suggested by **RolandoMySQLDBA On [MySql - Clean ibdata1 .](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16747/mysql-clean-ibdata1)**

Comment: If you remove them, a mysql startup will just regenerate them. Perhaps `--skip-innodb` should be added to `/etc/my.cnf` after shutting down and deleting, but before starting back up.