# Does MySQL's MyISAM use cache before insert?

Tags: mysql, myisam, cache

I want to test two different disks, one of them is HDD and another is SSD.

I use exactly the same information and app for both servers. They are exactly the same, just one of them is SSD and another is HARD.

When I run a simple script that inserts 1,000,000 rows into the database they take a similar time to run. Sometimes HARD is faster!

I want to know does MySQL's MyISAM use any caching, so I can get the same time to insert or I have same disk?

If they use cache before insert how can I disable that to test disk speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyISAM does not cache data at all. It caches only indexes ( See my post [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194) )

You could just set [**key_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_key_buffer_size) to something absurbly small, like 8 (the minimum allowed). You may as well disable the query cache while you're at it (Setting [**query_cache_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size) to 0).

Just add these lines to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
key_buffer_size = 8
query_cache_size = 0
```

and run `service mysql restart`

This will effectively disallow caching anything for MyISAM.

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-02-19 13:37 EDT

You just commented:

> Also if I understand correctly , you want to say InnoDB use Both INDEX AND Data in memory , so it should have faster speed than MyISAM , but I saw MyISAM insert speed is 10 time faster than InnoDB, why ?

Believe it or not, it is possible to tune MyISAM to outperform InnoDB

- `Jul 06, 2012` : [MySQL table with 100,000 records queried often](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/mysql-table-with-100-000-records-queried-often/20503#20503)
- `May 03, 2012` : [Which is faster, InnoDB or MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/which-is-faster-innodb-or-myisam/17434#17434)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Best of MyISAM and InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5974/best-of-myisam-and-innodb/6008#6008)

Comment: WOW , I think you have great mind on Database ! Do you have any book on performance ?

Comment: Also if I understand correctly , you want to say InnoDB use Both INDEX AND Data in memory , so it should have faster speed than MyISAM , but I saw MyISAM insert speed is 10 time faster than InnoDB , why ?