# What's the optimal server configuration for fastest inserting in a MySql database in this scenario?

Tags: mysql, optimization, myisam, partitioning

I have a MyISAM table partitioned by range with 90 partitions representing the last 90 days. I expect this table to receive somewhere between 500 million to 1 billion records before i start rotating partitions (dropping old ones and creating new ones).

What server configuration options would you put in your `.my.conf` file to ensure that the fastest possible insertion into this table was possible at all times?

Any other tips would also be appreciated.

EDIT: By 'fastest possible' i mean best possible insert speed and being sustained once it contains 100's of millions of rows.

Answer (score 4):

There are two major things you can change. One involves the table and one involves a config setting.

## TABLE CHANGE

You can increase SELECT and INSERT speed by changing the MyISAM table's row format to FIXED. In order to do do, you would run

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.mytable ROW_FORMAT=Fixed;
```

There is a drawback to this: This could potentially increase the table size 80-100%

I have discussed changing MyISAM row format before

- `May 10, 2011` : [What is the performance impact of using CHAR vs VARCHAR on a fixed-size field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field/2643#2643)
- `Aug 12, 2011` : [Which DBMS is good for super-fast reads and a simple data structure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/which-dbms-is-good-for-super-fast-reads-and-a-simple-data-structure/4589#4589)
- `Jul 06, 2012` : [MySQL table with 100,000 records queried often](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20493/mysql-table-with-100-000-records-queried-often/20503#20503)
- `Sep 26, 2012` : [Choosing MyISAM over InnoDB for these project requirements; and long term options](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24951/choosing-myisam-over-innodb-for-these-project-requirements-and-long-term-option/24968#24968)

## CONFIG SETTING

MyISAM supports a special protocol called a concurrent insert. It works by appending new rows to a MyISAM as long as there are no gaps as a result of DELETEs.

Here is some good news: you can disable the gap check for concurrent insert

```
[mysqld]
concurrent_insert = 2
```

According to the [MySQL Documentation on `concurrent_insert`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_concurrent_insert), here is what happens for value 2:

> Enables concurrent inserts for all MyISAM tables, even those that have holes. For a table with a hole, new rows are inserted at the end of the table if it is in use by another thread. Otherwise, MySQL acquires a normal write lock and inserts the row into the hole.

If the table is being heavily read, new INSERTs just get appended. When you are the only DB connection with a file handle to the table, then a normal gap check is done.

See the [MySQL Documentation on Concurrent Inserts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/concurrent-inserts.html)

## EPILOGUE

These two changes combined may produce surprising performance results. Why? Using `ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic` would trigger a search for a gap large enough to hold a new row. If the table has `ROW_FORMAT=Fixed`, all gaps are the same size. A new row insertion would be as quick as possible because the first gap row searched is used immediately for the insertion.