# How to update a (very) large table without locking in MySQL

Tags: mysql, myisam, locking, update

I have a large table (58+ million records) which represents a relation between two records (player and target) in a second table.

Unfortunately, whoever designed our schema didn't think things through properly, and opted to use usernames to represent this relation, instead of the numerical ids for the user records. As things progressed (like they usually do), our usernames are no longer a valid, unique representation of a player so I need to convert these relations to use numerical ids.

Adding the fields without locking was easy thanks to Percona Toolkit, which offers pt-online-schema-change that can ALTER on a live table. Populating the tables, however might be trickier.

The tables looks like this (I've stripped the creates of non-relevant fields), with the two unpopulated fields being `player_id` and `target_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE `player_targets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `player_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `target` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `target_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=58000000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE 'player_uuids' (
  `id`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=600000 DEFAUL CHARSET=latin1;
```

I was planning on populating the two new fields with a query like this one:

```
UPDATE player_targets t
INNER JOIN player_uuids u1
  ON u1.username = t.player
INNER JOIN player_uuids u2
  ON u2.username = t.target
SET
  t.player_id = u1.id,
  t.target_id = u2.id
WHERE
  t.player_id IS NULL
  OR t.player_id IS NULL;
```

With the table storing relations being MyISAM, my interpretation of the documentation is that the UPDATE-query will lock the table until it's finished with all the rows. As the table is large, this will likely not work very well in a live environment.

What would the best approach for this be? writing a script to iterate over batches of relations? Changing the table engine to InnoDB (the table is read-heavy, which I believe is the reason for it being MyISAM)?

Comment: If your queries need to change to refer to the new fields anyways, why not put the properly-normalized relation into a new table?

Comment: That's certainly an option - it does raise the concern of making our, already very complex, queries even more complex, with the added downside that we'll have to maintain both this poorly formatted schema and queries for a long time to come.

Am of the mindset that it's better to fix it properly now, than later :) I also have the benefit of scheduled downtime for some other parts of this overhaul, but am worried I won't have time to populate the entire table during that time, and wanted to pre-populate as much of it as possible.

Comment: No what I'm saying is, if you are migrating to int columns in the same table, in order to use it you need to update all the queries **anyways**. There's no extra work involved in putting it into a separate table.

Comment: I understood that - there is however extra work in putting it in a separate table, as that will require further joins on all queries that access the table. Sure, we will be updating the queries anyway, but do we really want to paint ourselves even further into a corner by keeping useless legacy data around?

Comment: It's no extra work - instead of adding fields to the existing table, you make a new table that only has the fields you need. Then the current table goes away and you have the same number of `JOIN`s.

Comment: Olle, @JNK is not suggesting to keep useless legacy data round. He is suggesting to have a new table and populate it with the numeric ids, without touching (writing to) the existing table. Then, when all is done, replace the old table with the new.

Comment: use common_schema or oak-chunk-update to perform the large operation with small chunks. https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/query_script_split.html

Comment: @ypercube - I totally misunderstood his suggestion, and took it as "create a new table with player_id, target_id and a reference to the old data". I guess my head was on backwards today - am going to blame it on English not being my first language. Copying it to a separate table would certainly work, but I'm not sure it be a time efficient way to do it; once copied I'd either have to rely on triggers to replicate writes to the new table to make sure both datasets are identical (as far as they should be so) or do a final update-run while being offline.

Comment: @eroomydna - thanks, I'll look into that. Just from a quick glance, that looks like the kind of solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can delete or update by one row in loop statement. In this case there will be no blocking but it will work a little slower. Use limit 1 to do this in procedure:

```
  PROCEDURE myProcedure()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE c int; -- to calculated affected rows
    set c = 0;

      ml:LOOP
          UPDATE player_targets t
          INNER JOIN player_uuids u1
           ON u1.username = t.player
          INNER JOIN player_uuids u2
           ON u2.username = t.target
          SET
           t.player_id = u1.id,
           t.target_id = u2.id
          WHERE
           t.player_id IS NULL
           OR t.player_id IS NULL 
           LIMIT 1;

          -- check if the loop has completed    
          IF  ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
              LEAVE ml;
          END IF;    

          set c = c + 1;

          IF c MOD  100  = 0 THEN
              SELECT CONCAT(c, ' row(s) updated');
          END IF;
      END LOOP;  

      SELECT CONCAT(c, ' row(s) updated; The statement has completed');
    END
```

And call procedure:

```
Call myProcedure();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iterate over batches.  [This blog provides some suggestions on how to do it](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

It is couched in how to chunk up big `DELETE`s, but the principles work for big `UPDATE`s, like yours.

It shows you how to walk through using (typically) the `PRIMARY KEY` and use `LIMIT` to decide on the next chunk.  No step has to scan the entire table as that would defeat the purpose of chunking.

Answer (score 0):

> What would the best approach for this be? writing a script to iterate over batches of relations? Changing the table engine to InnoDB (the table is read-heavy, which I believe is the reason for it being MyISAM)?

Change the table to InnoDB. Not just to eliminate table locking reasons. But, for crash recovery, referential integrity and a bunch of other stuff. See [this answer for the nitty gritty.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1/2639)

Why would you want a work around? MyISAM is fine to use, but you should have a reason. So you *think* your DB is read-heavy. Try the hardened default that MySQL provides and if that fails your use-case then you may want to try something else MySQL offers. I wouldn't even want to consider something before trying InnoDB. That's the easy solution: try a different storage engine.