# Innodb using key cache?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-tuning

As `Innodb` is my default engine, all my tables are innodb. But while monitoring with the help of a tool, I found a constant spike in `key_write_requests` and `key_read_requests`. These two variables are `myisam` variables. Will innodb internally use key cache for any process? Is it possible?

Comment: What is your default MySQL engine.

Comment: Innodb @MdHaidarAliKhan

Comment: Could you update , which Mysql version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Md Haidar Ali Khan said, ...
The "default storage engine" does not mean that you created all the tables in that engine.  You should verify with `SHOW TABLE STATUS;` for you database(s).  That will say, among other things, what Engine is being used.

`innodb_buffer_pool_size`, for an InnoDB-only system, should be set to about 70% of available RAM (if RAM is at least 4GB).  And set `key_buffer_size` to some small value, say, 20M because of system tables that are in MyISAM.  These system tables probably caused the spikes you saw.

[*More discussion of memory*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory) -- including what to do if you *are* using MyISAM.

Comment: ,+1 for RAM. I learn here something extra as if there will be all tables in 'InnoDB engine' only then 'innodb_buffer_pool_size should be 70% of RAM.(If RAM is at least 4GB). impress with your  link of MySQL Blog.

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL Documentation 'InnoDB' maintains a storage area called the `buffer pool` for `caching` data and `indexes` in `memory`.
Innodb maintain their Buffer Pool through `LRU Algorithm`.

As Table,data & indexes Storing Format of both MyISAM & Innodb is different ways like `MyISAM stores its tables, data and indexes in diskspace using separate three different files`. (`tablename.FRM`, `tablename.MYD`, `tablename.MYI`) and `InnoDB stores its tables and indexes in a tablespace`.

For Ref [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) & [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam)