# Row size too large (> 8126)

Tags: mysql, limits

I have a table with 156 columns and most of them are either VARCHAR(1000) or TEXT.

Now, when entering data into one such row, I get

> mysql_error() = Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to
>   TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may
>   help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored
>   inline.

I am thinking of changing the table type to MyISAM.
Its on a shared server, but can setup a [private MySQL instance](https://docs.webfaction.com/software/private-databases.html#private-mysql-instances).

From [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15) :

> InnoDB implements transactions, foreign keys and relationship
>   constraints, MyISAM does not.

I can still use JOINS etc on MyISAM, right ? I'm not implementing any other complex stuff on these tables.

Comment: the best choice - split the table

Comment: I would have to re-write a lot of code to pull and insert info from and to the tables.

Comment: Well, first of all you can define the engine on a per-table basis, you don't need a new instance. But you might face a new problem then: in contrast to InnoDB, MyISAM counts `varchar(1000)` as length 1000 (or 3000 with utf8), no matter if you put shorter string in it (but has a limit of 64k, so it might work). Anyway, I agree with vlad, you should try to redesing your table structure. MyISAM is an old format that should not be used anymore, and is removed in the newest MySQL version (8). I assume you cannot upgrade to 5.7?

Comment: At present, cannot upgrade to 5.7, but what's new in 5.7 ?

Comment: 5.7 defaults to Barracuda file format, which would allow you to use the dynamic row format. That is what is proposed in the error message. But you should set the format permanently in the server configuration (if you can do that in the private instance, that would be fine), it is risky to do it temporarily, as any further `alter` to the table (without setting the file format again) would revert that and truncate your data (without warning first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5.5.14 and 5.6.3 and 5.7 have `innodb_file_format=Barracuda` as an option.

Prior to 5.7.7, do these:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;
logout & login (to get the global values);
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

In 5.7.7 and after, most of that is defaulted as you need.

`DYNAMIC` is the format you need -- it leaves only 22 bytes in the main part of the row (which is limited to about 8KB), and puts the rest in overflow blocks.  This applies to `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `VARBINARY` and `BLOB`.  22*156 is well under 8K.  "When the row is too long, InnoDB chooses the longest columns for off-page storage."  That is, some of the shorter columns for a given row may still reside 'on-page'.

I think the "22" is a 2-byte length, plus a 20-byte "pointer" to the data.  That is, none of the data is stored 'on-page', and the 768 is not relevant.

Another possibility (but I don't recommend it) is to increase the default page size from 16KB to 32KB, thereby increasing the max from about 8K to about 16K.  (There is a 64KB page size, but the limit is still 16KB for each row.)

Also, `COMPRESSED` can be used instead of `DYNAMIC`, but again, I don't recommend it, especially before 5.7.  ("Compressed = Dynamic plus compression.")

Splitting the table ("vertical partitioning") is a good idea.

MyISAM is a bad idea.

Checking to see if you *really* need 1000 is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same issue and I resolved it by using text data type instead of using varchar, I know it is not the good practice and not a proper way to resolve this issue but it will work fine