# Changed MyISAM to InnoDB, huge performance loss

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, performance, performance-tuning

So I'm testing on our dev server to change MyISAM to InnoDB and am having a huge performance loss.

Here is my.cnf:

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_buffer_pool_instance=2
innodb_log_file_size=512M
key_buffer_size=24M
#70% of available RAM
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3072M
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_io_capacity=5000
```

I'm running a Amazon CentOS t2.medium instance (2 vCPU & 4 GB ram).

Here are a few tests I ran. I ran alot more but with the same theme. InnoDB takes way longer and loads the CPU more.
[image]

Anyone have any thoughts? I've read if you have a lot of INSERTS / UPDATES with big data InnoDB is way better then MyISAM. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Although written in 2007, some good info in this article, "Innodb Performance Optimization Basics" [link](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/11/01/innodb-performance-optimization-basics/).

Answer (score 0):

You said in your question

> I've read if you have a lot of INSERTS / UPDATES with big data InnoDB is way better then MyISAM. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Your server class is too small for your InnoDB settings.

[On `Apr 14, 2011`, I mentioned how the storage engines have distinct ways of caching](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194).

- MyISAM will only cache indexes in RAM. Data is always read from disk.
- InnoDB caches data and indexes in the InnoDB Buffer Pool

I also noted how your innodb_read_io_threads and innodb_write_io_threads are maxed out. You only have 4GB of RAM or which you only have 1GB free (due to your 3GB or 3072M Buffer Pool). I would lower your threads from 64 to 8.

If you have the budget, you should go upgrade your server class to `m3.large` or `m3.xlarge` where you can have 4 CPU and 15 or 16G of RAM. You could then increase innodb_buffer_pool_size to 10G or 12G. Then, your remaining InnoDB settings would make sense. I would still lower your threads from 64 to 8.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. But I thought the point of changing to InnoDB was to be more efficient and save money.

Answer (score -1):

The structure of MyISAM and InnoDB are not the same:

## MyISAM

When do dml(ex:insert) it's just store in memory and then push it after that.(bad when server crush)

## InnoDB

need to syncs that data to disk until finished it cost the disk I/O.

## Hint

1. you can set you transaction to autocommit=0;
2. https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6470